# Issues about definition of almost surely convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $Y_n:=n^2{\bf 1}_{[0,1/n]}(U)$ where $U\sim \mathcal{U}([0,1]).$

I don't see why we have the equality $$P(\{\omega\in\Omega\;;\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_n=0\})=P(U\in(0,1])\;?$$

I have another question I have some issues to understand convergence almost surely of random variables.

For exemple let $(X_n)_n$ be a sequence of random variables such that the distribution is uniform on $[-\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}]$, how can I look at the convergence almost surely of $X_n$ ?

Comment: Are you sure $Y_n$ is written correctly? If $U$ is uniformly distributed in $(0,1)$ then since for any $n>1$, that $[1,1/n]=\emptyset$ we have $P(1<U<1/n)=0$...

Comment: @NapD.Lover typo, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to return to probability space in second question. If $X_n\sim \mathcal U[-\frac1n,\frac1n]$ than $\mathbb P(|X_n|\leq \frac1n)=1$ and also $\mathbb P(|X_n|\leq \frac1n, n=1,2,\ldots)=1$. The event $\{|X_n|\leq \frac1n, n=1,2,\ldots\}$ implies the event $\{|X_n|\to 0 \text{ as }n\to\infty\}$, so
$$
1=\mathbb P(|X_n|\leq \frac1n, n=1,2,\ldots)\leq\mathbb P(|X_n|\to 0).
$$
Then $\mathbb P(|X_n|\to 0)=1$.

Comment: oh really nice thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If $U(w) \in (0,1]$, then there exists $N$ such that $U(\omega) > 1/N$. Then for all $n\geq N$ we have $Y_{n}(\omega)=0$, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}Y_{n}(\omega)=0$. Conversely, if $U(w)=0$ then $Y_{n}(\omega)=n^{2}$ for all $n$, and so $Y_{n}(\omega)\to \infty$.

Thus $Y_{n}(\omega)\to 0$ iff $U(\omega)\in(0,1]$.

For the second question, you really need to be more specific about the underlying probability space and probability measure, but I'll just assume we're working on $[-1,1]$ with normalized Lebesgue measure (i.e. divide by 2, which is the length of the interval $[-1,1]$).

I claim that $X_{n}\to 0$ a.s. Indeed, if $\omega\neq 0$, then there exists $N$ such that $|\omega|>1/N$ for all $n\geq N$. Therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}X_{n}(\omega)=0$ if $\omega\neq 0$. Since $\mathbb{P}([-1,1]\setminus\{0\})=1$, we have $X_{n}\to 0$ a.s.

Comment: great, thank you, can you help for the other second as well ?

Comment: @TTL updated my answer